# Understanding a paragraph on pg.145 in Royden (4th edition).

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, uniform-convergence

The paragraph is given in the picture below:

> [image]

**My question is: **

1- Why for a sequence $\{f_{n}\}$ and a function $f$ in $C[a,b],$ $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ in $C[a,b],$ normed by the maximum norm, iff $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $[a,b].$ could anyone give me a proof for such statement please?

2-Also, I do not understand why the second statement is true, could anyone explain it for me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f_n$ and $f$ are continuous and $\|f_n-f\|_{\infty} \to 0$ and $\epsilon >0$ then there exists $n_0$ such that $n >n_0$ implies $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq  \epsilon$ almost everywhere.  If $E$ is any set of measure $0$ in $[a,b]$ the $E^{c}$ is dense. Hence $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq  \epsilon$  holds on  a dense  set of points and continuity shows that the inequality holds for all $x$. Hence $f_n \to f$ uniformly.

Suppose $\|f_n-f\|_{\infty} \to 0$ but we do not have any continuity assumption. Let $k$ be a postive integer Then there exists $n_0$ such that $n >n_0$ implies $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq \frac  1 k$ almost everywhere. Let $E_k$ be  set of measure $0$ such that the inequality holds whenever $x \notin E_k$. Let $E=\bigcup_k E_k$. Then the inequality holds for every $k$ for $x \notin E$. Hence $f_n \to f$ uniformly on the complement of $E$.

Comment: Is uniform convergence definition you are using differs from the one given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence?

Comment: In the first statement the norm is the maximum norm.

Comment: So in the first case why the small $n_{0}$ is independent on $x$ .... can you describe your thoughts by mathematical symbols please?