# Why the convergence is uniform here?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, uniform-convergence

I was reading a proof that creates a function to prove the completion of $C[a,b]$ with the maximum norm and the author wrote:

Let $(f_{n})$ be a Cauchy sequence in $C[a,b].$ Fix $x \in [a,b],$ then by the definition of a Cauchy sequence we have $$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: \|f_{n} - f_{m}\| _{max} < \epsilon \quad \forall m,n \geq N. \quad (*) $$ 
But by definition of the maximum norm $|f_{n}(x) - f_{m}(x)| \leq \|f_{n} - f_{m}\| _{max}.$ Therefore , there exists $N$ such that  $$ |f_{n}(x) - f_{m}(x)| < \epsilon  \quad \forall m,n \geq N. \quad (**)$$ Hence, $(f_{n}(x))$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}.$

Then the author said by $(**),$  there exists $N$ such that  $$ |f_{n}(x) - f_{m}(x)| < \epsilon  \quad \forall x \in [a,b] \quad  \forall m,n \geq N.$$

And hence the convergence is uniform.

**My question is :**

How $(**)$ give us this uniform convergence? could anyone explain this for me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property $(\ast)$ gives you an $N$ dependent only on $\varepsilon$ for the Cauchyness of the sequence $(f_n)$ in the $\|\cdot\|_{\text{max}}$ metric.

So that $N$ also works for all $x$ simultaneously for that $\varepsilon$ because for any $x$ we have $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)| \le \|f_n -f_m\|_{\text{max}}$, so the sequence $(f_n(x))_n$ is Cauchy in $\Bbb R$ for any fixed $x$, and thus converges to some point which we define to be $f(x) \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: but why the arbitrariness leads us to put the $\forall x$ sign after $\exists N$ sign ? we can change the order and the arbitrariness will remain also.

Comment: @Idonotknow You don't change the order. The max norm implies that the inequality holds for all $x$.

Comment: are you saying that this property is true because of the properties maximum norm?

Comment: @Idonotknow essentially yes. $\|f_n -f_m\| < \varepsilon$ implies $\forall x: |f_n(x) - f_m(x)| < \varepsilon$

Answer (score 1):

Take $\varepsilon>0$. You know that there is a $N\in\mathbb N$ such that$$(\forall x\in[a,b])(\forall m,n\in\mathbb N):m,n\geqslant N\implies\bigl\lvert f_n(x)-f_m(x)\bigr\rvert<\frac\varepsilon2.$$But then, if $x\in[a,b]$ and $n\geqslant N$,\begin{align}\bigl\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\bigr\rvert&=\left\lvert f_n(x)-\lim_{m\to\infty}f_m(x)\right\rvert\\&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\bigl\lvert f_n(x)-f_m(x)\bigr\rvert\\&\leqslant\frac\varepsilon2\\&<\varepsilon.\end{align}

Comment: It is not clear for me how what you did satisfies the definition of uniform convergence .... could you clarify please? how this makes the $N$ independent of $x$?

Comment: Is the convergence uniform because our $x$ was arbitrary?

Comment: @Idonotknow essentially yes, because this works for all $x$.

Comment: @Idonotknow I proved that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is a natural $N$ such that$$\bigl(\forall x\in[a,b]\bigr)(\forall n\in\mathbb N):n\geqslant N\implies\bigl\lvert f(x)-f_n(x)\bigr\rvert<\varepsilon.$$Isn't that what uniform convergence *means*?

Comment: this definition does not clarify enough the difference beteen uniform and pointwise convergence which I was searching for.

Comment: The difference is that, when working with uniform convergence, we search a $N$ which works for every $x$; in pointwise convergence, we only have to find, for each $x$, a number $N$ which works for *that* $x$.

Comment: yes, but this is not clear from that definition. Anyway, thank you soo much for your patience in helping me.  Also could you please look at this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3457678/understanding-a-paragraph-on-pg-145-in-royden-4th-edition if you do not mind . as I do not understand the solution given there